# How can I mark with `final` classes generated by xjc?

Tags: java, gradle, jaxb, xjc

I'm using `xjc` in `gradle` as follows:

```
task xjc(type: JavaExec) {
  inputs.files(schemaDir)
  outputs.dir(generatedSrcDir)

  main = 'com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver'
  classpath = configurations.xjc
  jvmArgs '-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all'
  args    '-quiet',
          '-d',
          "$generatedSrcDir",
          '-classpath',
          "$configurations.xjc.asPath",
          '-disableXmlSecurity',
          '-extension',
          '-npa',
          '-no-header',
          '-enableIntrospection',
          '-Xxew',
          '-Xxew:instantiate lazy',            
          '-Xcomments',
          '-Xcomments-mode=replace',
          '-Xequals',
          '-Xhashcode',
          '-Xtostring',
          "$schemaDir",
          '-b',
          "$schemaDir"

   doFirst {
      // Create directory for generated sources if not exists
      mkdir(generatedSrcDir)

      println "Generating JAXB sources with XJC version $jaxbVersion ..."
  }

}
```

I need to know if I could mark with `final` all classes suitable?

P.S. Point of `final` here is to preserve the equals contract for generated classes.

Comment: There is a project called immutable-xjc that might fit your needs. Check it out : https://github.com/sabomichal/immutable-xjc